# What does $v = v_0 + t_1v_1 + t_2v_2$ parameterize?

Tags: parametric

> Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be given vectors. $v = t_1v_1 + t_2v_2$ varies over the plane determined by the two vectors. The plane is parameterized by $t_1$ and $t_2$.
>   Let $v_0$ be another given vector. What does $v = v_0 + t_1v_1 + t_2v_2$ parameterize?

I'd say that would be a plane since $v_0$ is a single non-scaled vector. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the whole plane being moved by the vector $v_0$. What then do you get?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the movement, please. I don't understand how or why $v_0$ moves the whole plane.

Comment: By movement, I meant translation.

Comment: For example, let $v=[1 \quad 1]$ and $v_0=[0 \quad 2]$. Vector $v$ can be viewed as moving from the the origin to the point $(1,1)$. Can you imagine what $v_0$ will do if it is added to $v$?

Comment: $v + v_0$ is the point $(1, 3)$. Is the original plane centered(?) at the origin? The way I imagine it is that $v = t_1v_1 + t_2v_2$ describes the plane completely, so $v_0$ is redundant and has no effect.

Comment: "...  so $v_0$ is redundant and has no effect" - That's correct! 

That's what I meant when I said $v_0$ "moves" the plane. Any movement will still result to the same plane.